# Declaring a Matrix with the same values with openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have declared a Matrix which contains values equal to 1:
    cv::Mat mat_cal = cv::Mat::ones(width, height, CV_8U);

Now I want to to be multiplied by a constant, I mean, one matrix whose values are equal to A=0.3
Then I wrote:
    cv::Mat mat_cal = cv::Mat::ones(width, height, CV_8U)*A;

But, the result? Matrix of 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0.....

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is your matrix type is `CV_8U` which is an 8-bit unsigned integer - as such `0.3` gets trunctated to `0`. Instead set it to `CV_32F` (32-bit floating point).

Also, if I remember, when multiplying by a scalar, you do as below. Multiplying 2 matrices doesn't work the same way:

```
float A = 0.3;
cv::Mat mat_cal = cv::Mat::ones(width, height, CV_32F)*A;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char i = 1;
i *= 0.3;
```

result ? 0

it's just plain old integer rounding.

if you want a Mat with double or float values, use the right type in the first place:

```
cv::Mat::ones(width, height, CV_32F)*0.3f; // float
```

or:

```
cv::Mat::ones(width, height, CV_64F)*0.3;  // double
```

Comment: To be a pedant - it's not rounding, it's truncation. Rounding implies that if `double i >= 0.5;`, `int(i) = 1;`, whereas in fact `int(i) = 0`;.